# Does wall of force allow heat through? Can it be used as insulation?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic

Wall of Force states

> Nothing can physically pass through the wall.

Is thermal energy, heat, a "thing" that can pass through a wall? Could you use wall of force to insulate yourself from a very cold, or very warm, environment, assuming you don't suffocate?